# PHP on Linux: can't remember $_SESSION variables

Tags: php, apache, session

I moved my pages over from EasyPHP on Windows to a Linux server, and developed this new problem.  When I reload the page, or click on a link to take me back to that page (or to another) that should be accessible in the session, the session information is lost, and the user is logged out.

This snippet of code adapted from `W3` seems to illustrate the problem:

```
<?php

//Thing1.php
session_start();
if (! isset ($_SESSION['views'])) $_SESSION['views']='first load';
else $_SESSION['views']='reloaded';
?>

<html>
<body>

<?php
//retrieve session data
echo "Pageviews=". $_SESSION['views'];
?>
<br>
<a href="thing1.php">Reload this page</a>

</body>
</html>
```

On EasyPHP, it initially displays `Pageviews=first load`, but after refreshing or clicking the link back to the same page, it always says `Pageviews = reloaded`.

On my Linux box, it always displays `Pageviews=first load`.  This is consistent with when I print the `$_SESSION` array, which is always empty.

The Linux box is running PHP 5.3.10-1unbuntu3.6 and Apache 2.2; EasyPHP has PHP 5.4.4 and Apache 2.4.2.

What I want here is the behavior under EasyPHP: for the Linux version also to remember `$_SESSION` variables.

Thanks

Comment: Sure you want that. But you need to find out what prevents you from that *first* to actually fix the problem. You need to troubleshoot your issue first. Do you have fundamental understanding how the session works? Have you double-checked nothing is standing in your way? Have you endable error logging in PHP and raised the level to the highest possible setting? Anything interesting in the error log then probably?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Look in your cookies to see if there is one called PHPSESSID.
2) look for session.save_path in your php.ini file. Go to that path and see if you see files.

If either one of these is not true, there is a problem with your session configuration.  In particular, make sure sessions are turned on - you may have to edit php.ini and fix the directory for session.save_path - instead of the default "/tmp" use a Windows directory like "c:/temp".

Comment: I do have a PHPSESSID cookie.  session.save_path is not set in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini or /etc/php5/cli/php.ini.  ... so I set it to /tmp in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and restarted apache [link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/star-stop-restart-apache2-webserver/).  It works!  That was the problem.  Thanks --!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that `session_start()` is called on the 2nd page as well as the 1st, and make sure that there is no HTML or PHP output (echo, print, etc) before you call `session_start()`.

Comment: Edited the problem to make it clearer -- at this point, there's only one page, and it does `session_start()` first.  so that's handled...

Comment: Ahh, sorry about that. Don't suppose you get a different result if you hard refresh the page when testing?

Comment: Refreshed or loaded through link, either way, no $_SESSION vars.

Comment: Thanks! this worked for me... I have html tags before the session_start(). I just moved it to the top of the file and it worked fine!